# Use www.domain or leave it out when using absolute url's linking to web assets on a web page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

When I use PHP includes to import code in other pages I typically have to use absolute paths when linking to another page on the site or an image asset.

It is considered best practice to use absolute paths when linking to assets.

This leaves an issue when someone accesses the site with either domain.com or www.domain.com

I find things break when someone uses the www where I left it out in the absolute paths.

What is the correct method to solve for this?

To solve for this, I've typically had .htaccess forward the site to either domain.com or www.domain.com depending on what I've used in the absolute paths, but I'm not sure if that's the right solution.

In htaccess I either ensure the site forwards with the www or without:

## add www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

## Remove www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: If I understand your issue correct, then you should use relative urls from the root: `/path/to/asset` (the initial slash means that it is from the document root). Without the initial slash, it will be relative from the URL you're currently on.

Comment: absolute links are the best practice but in this situation we cant know whats causing your problem can provide some code of you links

Comment: With `include` or `require` you should be using the filesystem path anyway, not the URL, so the domain wouldn't necessarily make the blindest bit of difference (unless it's on a different DOCROOT)...

Comment: I've added a little more info. To sum up, do you use www in the domain or not in an absolute path? And how to ensure an absolute path is not broken if someone access the site using www when you've left it out of the absolute path.